# yowsup installation on windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, yowsup

I am following these procedures for installation:
https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/blob/master/README.md

and completed yowsup2 installation successfully with this command

```
pip install yowsup2
```

and now I am trying to register my phone number in yowsup 
as suggested [here](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/wiki/yowsup-cli-2.0)

but when I tried following command (yowsup is imported) it gives error

```
>>> yowsup-cli
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cli' is not defined
```

I am new to python

Please help me to solve this error :/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but in case you are still interested (and haven't solved your problem already!), I also came across this problem recently.
I'm assuming you're running Windows (otherwise you can follow the [instructions for Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177294/how-to-setup-and-use-yowsup-cli-to-to-get-whatsapp-authentication-code))

If you navigate to `Scrips` in your Python directory (usually `C:\Python`, or in the AppData folder) after you have installed yowsup with pip, you should find the `yowsup-cli` file sitting in there somewhere... without an extension.
I'm not sure why this is, but renaming it to a python file fixed this issue for me.

Lastly, make sure that Scrips is in your PATH, so that python knows where to find it. This should be the case anyway, but there is no harm in double checking

Answer (score 0):

this problem occured because your cmd can not find the yowsup-cli or can not find python. check your environment variables ,that you have set your python path or not,if not then see some videos and set it. Or type

```
python yowsup-cli
```

and that will mostly run it.